# How to connect to remote desktop from Lucid Lynx (with tsclient) to XP (with UltraVNC)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-xp, remote-desktop

I am trying to connect to my laptop using tsclient in ubuntu and UltraVNC in XP.

I open tsclient in linux, enter the laptop IP and protocol = RDP, hit connect and it opens the windows logon, I can connect and login, but its not using UltraVNC (its running on the XP), I know this because I close UltraVNC from the remote desktop and the connection still works so it seems its using the windows built in remote desktop.

**How can I connect to UltraVNC instead of XP default remote desktop?**

I want to do this because I read UltraVNC works better for screen refreshs, my currently remote desktop connection works really bad for screen refreshs.

Answer (score 0):

`tsclient` is for Remote Desktop Protocol, you should use Remote Desktop Viewer (`vinagre`) for vnc protocol.